# Why is my css not working only on certain part of my code?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I wrote some css code, which must've change font-family of my table. It's working somewhere and somewhere it's not. I don't understand what's the problem.

I tried to see if it will work with other font-families, but apparently it didn't.

CSS

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        table,th,td {
            border: 1px ridge  ;
            font-family: sans-serif;
         }
        #unique{
            font-size:  40px;
        }

        img{
            height: 350px;
            width: 350px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

HTML(part where it isn't working)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><img src="persons-0004_800x.png" alt="happy smile"></td>
        <td>Ժպիտ</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Սմայլիկ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Смайлик</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Smile</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

HTML(parts where its working properly)

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ամիս</th>
            <th>Գումար</th>
            <th>Ամբողջ գումարը</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Հունվար</td>
            <td>1000 դր.</td>
            <td rowspan="3">2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Փետրվար</td>
            <td>8000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Մարտ</td>
            <td>2000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br><br>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ամիս</th>
            <th>Գումար</th>
            <th>Ամբողջ գումարը</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Հունվար</td>
            <td>10000 դր.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">18000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Փետրվար</td>
            <td>8000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Մարտ</td>
            <td>2000 դր.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">4000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ապրիլ</td>
            <td>2000 դր.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br><br>

    <table id="unique">
        <tr>
            <th>Պարտքատեր</th>
            <th>Գումար</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Գումար</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Վարդան</td>
            <td>$300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Ամբողջը: $400</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you define not working please? because everything looks okey here

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><img src="persons-0004_800x.png" alt="happy smile"></td>
        <td>Ժպիտ</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Սմայլիկ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Смайлик</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Smile</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: This part is not working

Comment: yeah but not working how? you can't apply the font on it? because the font looks okey for me

Comment: Yeah,its sad. Thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#unique{
   font-family: inherit;
   font-size:  40px;
}
```

seems to work for me.